# Delete files created 5 mins or earlier in a folder

Tags: linux, cron, files, rm

On CentOS, how can I delete files which are created 5 mins ago or earlier in a folder? Thanks!

Comment: As a starting point, it would most likely involve crond, find and awk. I'll try and figure out the commands but there is probably someone on here more qualified than me to answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [find](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

```
find ./ -mmin -5 -exec rm -i '{}' \;
```

Comment: `find ./ -mmin -5` returns nothing .. even there are some old files in the current folder

Comment: find ./ -mmin -5 should return a list of all files modified in less than or equal to five minutes. I tested this on my Debian system with success. Regardless, you want to use find to do this...

Comment: `# find --version
GNU find version 4.2.27
Features enabled: D_TYPE O_NOFOLLOW(enabled) LEAF_OPTIMISATION SELINUX ` on CentOS

Comment: for files created 5 mins or earlier, it's `find . -cmin +5`. find . -cmin -5` is files created within last 5 minutes. `-cmin +5` is different from `-cmin 5`. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Simmilar to [kce](https://serverfault.com/questions/272568/delete-files-created-5-mins-or-earlier-in-a-folder/272571#272571):

```
find /path/to/folder -type f -cmin -5 -print0|xargs -r0 rm
```

Added a search for files only and used cmin instead of mmin as you asked for files created in the past five minutes.  I like to combine find with xargs.

In UNIX, we typically refer to them as directories, not folders.  I used your name in the path above.

Comment: I tried `find /tmp -type f -cmin -5` and it returns nothing (`find /tmp -type f` returns all files in `/tmp`. (CentOS)

Comment: OK.  Well, maybe there are really no files that new under /tmp.